# Finding max or min element of arraylist objects

Tags: java

Below is my code

```
class Ex{

    String id;
    double version;

    public Ex(String id, double version) {
        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(double version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Ex> list = new ArrayList<Ex>();

        Ex rec1 = new Ex("HR3-A1234", 0.00);
        Ex rec2 = new Ex("HR3-A1234", 0.01);
        Ex rec3 = new Ex("HR3-A1234", 1.00);
        Ex rec4 = new Ex("HR3-A2345", 0.00);
        Ex rec5 = new Ex("HR3-A2345", 0.01);
        Ex rec6 = new Ex("HR3-A3456", 0.01);
        Ex rec7 = new Ex("HR3-A3456", 1.00);
        Ex rec8 = new Ex("HR3-A4567", 0.01);

        list.add(rec1);
        list.add(rec2);
        list.add(rec3);
        list.add(rec4);
        list.add(rec5);
        list.add(rec6);
        list.add(rec7);
        list.add(rec8);
    }
}
```

Here,For every record I want to display max/min version for every record where id is same.I tried it but am able to get only one record i.e max/min version of all records,but I want max/min version of every similar id.

Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Even if it fails, please add the code you tried.

Comment: show us your code for searching? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using some data structures to store the minima and maxima, for example. This example adds a method to your `Main` that outputs both the minima and the maxima of the version numbers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Ex> list = new ArrayList<Ex>();

        Ex rec1 = new Ex("HR3-A1234", 0.00);
        Ex rec2 = new Ex("HR3-A1234", 0.01);
        Ex rec3 = new Ex("HR3-A1234", 1.00);
        Ex rec4 = new Ex("HR3-A2345", 0.00);
        Ex rec5 = new Ex("HR3-A2345", 0.01);
        Ex rec6 = new Ex("HR3-A3456", 0.01);
        Ex rec7 = new Ex("HR3-A3456", 1.00);
        Ex rec8 = new Ex("HR3-A4567", 0.01);

        list.add(rec1);
        list.add(rec2);
        list.add(rec3);
        list.add(rec4);
        list.add(rec5);
        list.add(rec6);
        list.add(rec7);
        list.add(rec8);

        displayMinMaxOfEach(list);
    }

    public static void displayMinMaxOfEach(List<Ex> exes) {
        // declare two maps for storing minumum and maximum values
        Map<String, Double> minExes = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        Map<String, Double> maxExes = new HashMap<String, Double>();

        // check each Ex in the list in order to get the minimum values
        exes.forEach((Ex ex) -> {
            if (minExes.containsKey(ex.getId())) {
                // if already contained, check if the new version is lower
                if (minExes.get(ex.getId()) > ex.getVersion()) {
                    // if it is lower, overwrite the old version number
                    minExes.put(ex.getId(), ex.getVersion());
                }
            } else {
                // if not already contained, just add it to the map
                minExes.put(ex.getId(), ex.getVersion());
            }
        });

        // check each Ex in the list in order to get the maximum values
        exes.forEach((Ex ex) -> {
            if (maxExes.containsKey(ex.getId())) {
                // if already contained, check if the new version is higher
                if (maxExes.get(ex.getId()) < ex.getVersion()) {
                    maxExes.put(ex.getId(), ex.getVersion());
                }
            } else {
                // if not already contained, just add it to the map
                maxExes.put(ex.getId(), ex.getVersion());
            }
        });

        // print minumum values from the minimum map
        System.out.println("Minimum versions:");
        minExes.forEach((id, version) -> {
            System.out.println(id + ": " + version);
        });

        // print maximum values from the maximum map
        System.out.println("Maximum versions:");
        maxExes.forEach((id, version) -> {
            System.out.println(id + ": " + version);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can split that method into half and pass a parameter if you look for min or max. Because currently it repeats the same code twice with a difference in the < and >

Comment: @VeselinDavidov You are totally right, this is not the best solution regarding minimum lines of code. This code is intended as an illustrative example to promote understanding of the operations.

Comment: yeah I totally agree I even upvoted because it works properly and looks cool by using streams. Just making a suggestion which I thought would make it easier to understand

Comment: @deHaar in the above code how come maxExes.get(ex.getId()) is version number?

Comment: `maxExes` is a `Map<String, Double>` which means that you store a numeric value and have a `String` as key. This is similar to an index in an array or a list (not the same!). In values: `"HR3-A1234"` is the key and accessing it by `maxExes.get("HR3-A1234")` (= `maxExes.get(ex.getId)`) gives you the currently stored value…

Comment: ok so that means if we access the key we get the value of it?am I right?

Comment: Exactly... Just try it a few times with some random values. Trying out will make you get it right.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve that. For example add values to a Map by ID. Or use the Streams API etc. I would give one simple solution -  Sort the array first and then go over it. For each ID you will get first the min value and then the max value. So here is some code to check which prints Min and Max per ID. If you have just one record for that ID it will print it as both min and max (you can play with it if you don't want it)

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Ex>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Ex o1, Ex o2) {  //Simple comparator ;)
            if (o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId()) != 0) {
                return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
            }
            return Double.compare(o1.getVersion(), o2.getVersion());
        }
    });

    String currentId=null;  //Iterate and print the results
    double previousValue=0;
    for (Ex ex : list) {
        if(!ex.getId().equals(currentId)) {
            if(currentId!=null) {
                System.out.println("Id:"+currentId+" Max:"+previousValue);  
            }
            currentId=ex.getId();
            System.out.println("Id:"+currentId+" Min:"+ex.getVersion());
        }
        previousValue=ex.getVersion();
    }
    System.out.println("Id:"+currentId+" Max:"+previousValue);
```